# C# Could not load file or assembly : NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pipe, .net-assembly, named-pipes

Any idea to solve this problem?

I just created a new project and I want tu use System.IO.Pipes
I install the package System.IO.Pipes with NuGet, he is my reference directory but when I try to build I have :

Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipes, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

Any Idea to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of your project?

Comment: .Net Core 2.1, just a command line application

Comment: Try to run VS as administrator and to run `Update-Package -reinstall` command in Package Manager console.

Comment: I solved the problem :D it's down in the comment but I can't put it has answer before 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following;

1. Clean solution
2. Rebuild solution

If this fails do the following;

1. Uninstall the package
2. Remove the DLL package from packages on your Solution held on your PC
3. Reinstall package

Comment: I try this but nothing changed. An intresting point is that I didn't had the DLL package in the folder. Is it possible that NuGet doesn't really install the package?

Comment: Humm, do you want to try -update-package-reinstall https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

Comment: It tells me "Nothing tu update". But in my reference list I have System.IO.Pipes with a blue icon next to it

Comment: I think you have installed a .net core package and you may of installed .net framework. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499745/nuget-package-reference-blue-icon-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Also try what they say on this page but nothing changed. And the NuGet options were already fine :/

Comment: I am guessing if the package not in your packages folder it’s not installed so probably worth just uninstalling the whole thing and reinstalling. But as it says “system” I am not sure if it should be in the packages folder. What does your nuget config say? Also what project have you installed? And what nugget package have you installed. Are they both .Net core? Or are they both .Net framework?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem a few months back. Updating the NuGet Package Manager, the clean the solution, Restart VS IDE and then reinstalling library worked for me.

Comment: It's a new project and when I want to update the Visual Studio extension (NuGet) it doesn't show me anything to update :/

Comment: @JimmyFraiture I think the problem might be with either .Net Core or the VS IDE installation.

Comment: I'm currently reinstalling all VS. We'll see if it change something. Thanks

Comment: Facing the same issue with all packaged that Nuget provides. I reinstalled VS, cleaned the solution, etc. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was a missing attribute in the .csproj file:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

> The CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies property is useful for plugin projects
> that have dependencies on other libraries. If you set this property to
> true, any NuGet package dependencies are copied to the output
> directory. That means you can use the output of dotnet build to run
> your plugin on any machine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem :

1. Uninstall VS IDE
2. Reinstall it with
3. Install .NET Framework and Core with the VS installer
4. Create a new .Net project

Thanks for your help.
It was probably due to a corrupted file in the .Net Framework package

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following;

1. Clean solution
2. Uninstall the package
3. VS IDE -> Tools -> Options
4. Nuget Package Manager -> General
5. Clean Nuget Cache
6. Reinstall package